# jmesa renders the html as text

Tags: java, javascript, html, jmesa

I'm using jmesa in Java directly using the tableModel.render() to get the HTML directly. Some of my web objects in my result lists contain HTML - example:

```
class blah {
    String email;
    public String getEmailLink() {
      return "<a href='" + email + "</a>"
    }
}
```

In my Java code I would just do this:

```
htmlRow.addColumn(new HtmlColumn("emailLink"));
```

jmesa is rendering this as text. How can I tell jmesa to render the text as-is to be html in the document?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the JMesa soure code](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/source/browse/trunk/jmesa/src/org/jmesa/view/html/editor/HtmlCellEditor.java?r=2184), `HtmlCellEditor` automatically escapes HTML.

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to override the default `HtmlCellEditor` with a different type... such as the bare-bones [`BasicCellEditor`](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/source/browse/trunk/jmesa/src/org/jmesa/view/editor/BasicCellEditor.java?r=2184).  It shouldn't be too much extra code:

```
HtmlColumn emailLinkColumn = new HtmlColumn("emailLink");
emailLinkColumn.setCellEditor(new BasicCellEditor());
htmlRow.addColumn(emailLinkColumn);
```

Another option to all of this is to create a custom CellEditor and have it create your `<a>` tag for you instead of doing it in your bean.  [This page](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/wiki/Editors) should get you started with custom CellEditors if you want to go that route.

BTW, if you are messing with just a value inside of a cell, overriding/replacing `CellEditor` is probably all you need (`CellEditor` it is analogous to the body of a `<td>`).  `CellRenderer` is concerned with the entire cell (analogous to the `<td>` as well as its contents).

Answer (score 1):

Use a HtmlCellRenderer as [shown in this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/wiki/CustomCellRendererTutorial).